# Chamar método Laravel 4 usando Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, laravel

Tenho a seguinte estrutura de rota no angular:

```
.when('/', {
    redirectTo: '/pages/signin'
})
 .when('/:page', { // we can enable ngAnimate and implement the fix here, but it's a bit laggy
    templateUrl: function($routeParams) {
        return 'app/views/pages/'+ $routeParams.page +'.html';
    },
    resolve: function($routeParams) {
        return {deps: app.resolveScriptDeps(['js/controller.'+$routeParams.page+'.js'])};
    },              
    controller: 'Dash'
})
```

Ela funciona muito bem, localiza os arquivos html de acordo com o que é passado na URL

No meu arquivo route.php, tenho essa rota:

```
Route::controller('api/usuarios', 'UsuariosController');
```

No UsuariosController tenho o seguinte método:

```
public function getDados(){

    return Response::json([
        'id' => '1',
        'texto' => 'TESTE TESTE ETSTE'
    ]);
}
```

No meu controller do angular, tenho esse método:

```
    $scope.getDados = function(){
    $http.get('api/usuarios/dados').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log('DATA', data); 
    }).
    error(function(data) {

    });
}

$scope.getDados();
```

Só que quando eu chamo esse método do angular, ele me da um erro 404

Alguma dica do que pode estar acontecendo?

Comment: O que seria esse `/dados` no seu `$http.get('api/usuarios/dados')`, não seria `get-dados`?

Comment: Se você está chamando uma saída json, não tem finalidade de carregar uma html.

Comment: Então, mas eu nao quero chamar um html, eu quero pegar esse JSON apenas

Comment: quando vc enviar essa url manualmente, o que acontece?
api/usuarios/dados

Comment: Me aparece esse erro:
Not Found

The requested URL /laravel/api/usuarios/get-dados was not found on this server.

Comment: então, o problema é que não existe essa rota. Mas e essa? /laravel/api/usuarios/dados

Comment: dá uma olhada aqui: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#testing-json-apis

Comment: Então, me da o mesmo erro
Eu não sei se eu preciso definir na rota do angular, se preciso definir na rota do Laravel, ta um tanto quanto confuso

Comment: Só para completar, eu uso o Laravel 4

Comment: Cara, a rota de saída para json é no laravel.

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#converting-to-arrays-or-json
Response::json($someArray) return $model->toJson(); não tem que definir nada no angular, a menos que você esteja fazendo saída Restful da api do angular js.

Comment: http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/consuming-external-services/consuming-restful-apis.html

Comment: Quando for assim, você terá toda uma regra de utilização.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: Execute o comando `php artisan route:list` na raiz do seu projeto e verifique se a rota "api/usuarios/dados" está na lista.

Answer (score 0):

Vai dar erro 404 mesmo se você não estiver chamado essa url da página principal.

Quando você usa `api/usuarios/dados`, você está definido que está fazendo uma chamada relativa. Isso pode ser o problema. Se estiver em uma página que contenha `meusite.com/usuarios` na url, a chamada do ajax passaria a ser `meusite.com.br/usuarios/api/usuarios/dados`, porque a url está relativa.

Você pode tentar colocar `/api/usuarios/dados`, para corrigir o problema.